# Is it possible to invert the python __main__ test - ie stop parsing

Tags: python

I'm dealing with a bunch of old (ie legacy - ie don't break them) python scripts in a directory, adding unittests and modularising them (ie adding `__init__.py`).

For the large number of "just scripts" they need to be changed to have the `__main__` guard so that they are not run when `unittest` runs discovery (or module import).

I can break them up

```
## imports and defs

## functions

if __name__ == '__main__':

   ## rest of script goes here
```

However this puts a big dent in the git history as everything needs to be reindented.

My preference would be to invert the test

```
if __name__ != '__main__':
   STOP_RUNNING_HERE

## rest of script goes here
```

The obvious thoughts for `STOP_RUNNING_HERE` are `return` (not valid) and `exit()` (I don't want to exit someone loading the code).

Is there any way the guard can be inverted like this?

PS:
I know I could just reformat, or move the "script/main" code out of this directory - I'm trying to avoid major changes - or keep all changes simply reviewable - as I said this is legacy code that has unknown usage in arcane build scripts - we don't have time to re-write everything correctly in one big go - I just want to improve where I can and leave alone as much as possible.

I'm convinced there probably isn't an answer, but couldn't find anyone answering the question specifically out on the internet.

Comment: I’d say bite the bullet and make use of `git`’s whitespace-change-ignoring options.

Comment: Likely not possible, since AFAIk there's not much of a difference between loading code and executing code in Python. So for the most part behaviour will be the same in most cases, hence `exit(0)` being insufficient.

Comment: @Ry - That's what I expected, the issue is that the whitespace change can be ignored manually during commands (`-w`), but breaks things like `blame` or patching/merging (hopefully not needed this is all legacy cruft)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no other way to invert the test besides using your original idea of indenting the rest of the script after the `if __name__ == '__main__'`.